# Can I save a Tensorflow keras predict method as an executable?

Tags: python, matlab, tensorflow, keras, exe

I am pretty new to Tensorflow and I am developing an application that prepares data in MATLAB, which calls Tensorflow in Python to train a neural net, and then the data processing gets done back in MATLAB. Ideally, the end user would not have to have Python or Tensorflow installed and I could just package all of the neural net training into one or two executables to call from MATLAB, but for now, I am just trying to find a way to save our Tensorflow predict method as an executable.

I've looked into wrapping the whole thing up in a PyInstaller function but I'd like to keep the training and evaluation separate.

If there is a nice way to do that, or if anyone has some intuition or ideas on this, I would be very grateful.